# logarithmic differentiation of fraction

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can some one help me with this problem: using logarithmic differentiation find the derivative of 
$$\frac {e^{2x} (x^3-2)^4}{x(3e^{5x} +1)}.$$ 
I got stumped its a fraction, has e in it, and I'm supposed to use logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: let the given fraction be a function $f$ of $x$, and take $\ln f(x)$. Differentiate both sides by $x$, which will give you $f'(x)/f(x)$. Now multiply both sides by $f(x)$, and ta-da, you have $f'(x)$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take natural logarithm from both sides of the given function:
$$y=\frac {e^{2x} (x^3-2)^4}{x(3e^{5x} +1)} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{align}\ln y&=\ln \frac {e^{2x} (x^3-2)^4}{x(3e^{5x} +1)}=\\
&=\ln (e^{2x} (x^3-2)^4)-\ln (x(3e^{5x} +1))=\\
&=2x+4\ln (x^3-2)-\ln x-\ln (3e^{5x}+1).\end{align}$$
Now take derivative (implicitly) from both sides:
$$\frac1y\cdot y'=2+\frac{12x^2}{x^3-2}-\frac1x-\frac{15e^{5x}}{3e^{5x}+1}$$
And the final answer is ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry: logarithmic differentiation of a fraction
$$
F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
consists in writing, formally, $\log F(x)=\log f(x)-\log g(x)$ and so
$$
\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}
$$
If you have more terms, it's no different. In your case $f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)$ and $g(x)=g_1(x)g_2(x)$ (write down the definitions for these functions), so $\log F(x)=\log f_1(x)+\log f_2(x)-\log g_1(x)-\log g_2(x)$ and
$$
\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}=\frac{f_1'(x)}{f_1(x)}+\frac{f_2'(x)}{f_2(x)}
-\frac{g_1'(x)}{g_1(x)}-\frac{g_2'(x)}{g_2(x)}
$$
Now just compute the derivatives and simplify.